# how to sort the words alphabetically with bubble sort python

Tags: python

```
nama = ('a', 'B', 'A')
for i in range(len(nama) - 1, 0, -1):
    for j in range(i):
        if nama[j] > nama[j + 1]:
            temp2=nama[j]
            nama[j]= nama[j+1]
            nama[j+1]=temp2
print(nama)
```

> Output code is `('A', 'B', 'a' )`
>   How to covert output to
>   `('A', 'a', 'B')` with bubble sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do that just because in ASCII `ord('a') = 97 > ord('A')` and `ord('a') > ord('B')` so if you use any sort operation for this list, it will always `['A','B','a']`

Answer (score 0):

Here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/ the bubble sorting algorithme in python to use it with strings you can make a dictionary with all characters and their values (you can put in the order you want 'a':1, 'A':2 etc...) `if dic[arr[j]] > dic[arr[j+1]] :` or use the ord function which returns an interger representing the unicode char `if ord(arr[j]) > ord(arr[j+1]) :`

```
def bubbleSort(arr): 
    n = len(arr) 

    # Traverse through all array elements 
    for i in range(n): 

        # Last i elements are already in place 
        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 

            # traverse the array from 0 to n-i-1 
            # Swap if the element found is greater 
            # than the next element 
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1] : 
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j] 

# Driver code to test above 
arr = [64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90] 

bubbleSort(arr) 

print ("Sorted array is:") 
for i in range(len(arr)): 
print ("%d" %arr[i]),
```